# Gradient boosting training loss increases at every iteration

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

Every iteration, the *train* loss is increasing.

```
      Iter       Train Loss   Remaining Time 
         1        5313.1014           22.51s
         2        5170.8669           21.21s
         3     1641863.7866           20.05s
         4     1640770.5703           18.86s
         5     1695332.9514           17.62s
         6     1689162.9816           16.42s
         7     1689562.3732           15.26s
         8     1803110.9519           14.08s
         9     1801803.5873           12.94s
        10     2274529.9750           11.77s
        11    17589338.0388           10.59s
        12  1121779686.7875           10.03s
        13 1071057062185277527192667544912333682394851905403317706031104.0000            
        14 1071057062185277527192667544912333682394851905403317706031104.0000            
        15 1071057062185277527192667544912333682394851905403317706031104.0000            
        16 1071057062185277527192667544912333682394851905403317706031104.0000            
        17 1071057062185277527192667544912333682394851905403317706031104.0000            
        18 1071057062185277527192667544912333682394851905403317706031104.0000            
        19 1071057062185277527192667544912333682394851905403317706031104.0000            
        20 1071057062185277527192667544912333682394851905403317706031104.0000
```

My input is a large matrix of 0s and 1s (vectorized words, as a sparse matrix), and my targets are integers:

```
array([131,  64,  64, 134,  32,  50,  42, 154, 124,  29,  64, 154, 137,
        64,  64,  64,  89,  16, 125,  64])
```

Perhaps there's something wrong with my code, but I doubt it. Here it is:

```
xgboost = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=20, 
                                     min_samples_leaf=2, 
                                     min_samples_split=3,
                                     verbose=10, max_features=20)
xgboost.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
```

My input shapes are:

```
<1544x19617 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 202552 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: Without more information, the following is just speculation. One thing I might wonder about would be that `max_features << n_features`. Boosting has been shown to potentially over-emphasize noise in the data, and given the few features relative to the (presumed) rank of your matrix it's possible the algorithm is iteratively putting more weight on what amounts to noise. Perhaps due to the small set of features considered per split (pseudo-noise) or the data itself (actual noise). You may also want to try a smaller learning rate.

Comment: That sounds like it would only make sense if this was about the validation data.

Comment: Ah, yes. I misread your post. The boosting/noise dynamic would only apply out-of-sample

Comment: Does this still happen if you explicitly use AdaBoost by changing the loss function (and reduce learning rate)?

Comment: It might also be interesting to see if your probabilities are exploding by using successive calls to fit with one estimator at a time and using the warm_start capability

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll need to check that out tomorrow.

Comment: So I only tried the lower learning rate and it works. If you want to explain this in an answer I will accept it. It will help future readers for sure.

Comment: Sure. Glad that solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the training loss suddenly explodes, it's sometimes because of getting stuck in a degenerate solution space. It's possible that reducing the learning rate may help (and appears to, in this case). In gradient boosting, the learning rate affects the impact of each successive tree on the existing predictions. By reducing the learning rate, the ability of any one tree to radically alter the overall predictions is lower, which can help avoid unexpectedly ending up in degenerate solution spaces.